# Does proving that there exists a maximum value in $[a,b]$ for a function $f(x)$ prove that there exists a minimum value too?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

I've seen several proofs, such as this one http://math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2000-2001/math41/EVTProof.pdf, of the extreme value theorem where the writer has proved there exists a maximum value of $f(x)$ in $[a,b]$ and does not prove that there exists a minimum value in the same interval. So, I was wondering if, perhaps by some theorem ( I'm assuming ts the boundless theorem), proving that there exists a maximum value of $f(x)$ in $[a,b]$ proves also that there exists a minimum value in the same interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just note that

- $f$ is continuous iff $-f$ is continuous, and
- $\min f(x)=-\max(-f(x))$.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Similar proof for the minimum apply in such case. So, yes a continuous function in a closed interval has a max and a min.

Comment: So is that why they usually do not prove the existence of a minimum value?

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that the continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of $-f$.

If you have some set $\mathcal F$ of real functions defined on $[a,b]$ that hold the following properties:

- $f\in\mathcal F\implies -f\in\mathcal F$
- Every function $f\in \mathcal F$ meets its maximum.

Then every function of $\mathcal F$ meets its minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you do not assume the continuity of the function $f$ and I wondered if it is not true with no continuous functions. I found the answer with the function below, where the part of the graph of $f$ that appears, in the neighborhood of zero, is what we need to answer the question.

[image]